# Modifying how CompositeRollingAppender renames files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've seen a lot of questions here on the different appenders log4j has, but none that seem to cover the issue I'm having.  Apologies if this is repeated anywhere.

I'm using a `CompositeRollingAppender` in our app since we need to roll the log file based on both time and size.  This works exactly as advertised, however we end up with files like:

```
myapp.log
myapp.log.2010-12-11
myapp.log.2010-12-11.1
myapp.log.2010-12-12
```

Is it possible to change the format of how log4j renames the files?  I'm sure there must be an elusive property *somewhere* that I've missed.  For example in the above situation I'd like something like:

```
myapp.log
myapp-2010-12-11.log
myapp-2010-12-11.1.log
myapp-2010-12-12.log
```

The point here being that the extension is still .log   Why you ask?  Because the administrators of our app have complained that they can't just double-click on the file to open it (I know, I know).  If they all have a .log extension this would not be the case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a kludge but you can include the `.log` literal in your date pattern. Of course your files will look like `myapp.log-2010-12-11.log`, but at least they could be opened by double-clicking.

Comment: Yes - I could do that I suppose.  I was kind of hoping that this was simply a modification of some property I was missing.  I could of course just extend a base appender to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CompositeRollingAppender` does not support the feature you want.  It's pretty limited in how it determines (on startup) if there is already an appropriate log file to be appending to.   It only supports tacking date and number on to the end of the configured static name.

You could try to use log4j extras [`CompositeTriggeringPolicy`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/CompositeTriggeringPolicy.html) but I don't know of a `RollingPolicy` that will include both date and window.

The choice for your administrators is to forgo the size limit on the files so you can use the [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) with a [`TimeBasedRollingPolicy`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html) with a

```
<param name="FileNamePattern" value="MyApp.%d{yyyy-MM-W}.log" />
```

or live with the current names or run a cron job to rename the files, but keep in mind that you cannot rename the files until the next day (or else you'll get file name collisions).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
<param name="FileNamePattern" value="C:\\logs\\MyApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
```